# How to group javascript object properties based on a portion of the key name?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

How do I loop over this javascript object structure to group each key by it's index.  For example `mobile_1` and `desktop_1` should be grouped.

Each `_1` should be together, and `_2`. and so on.

Here is the object:

```
{
"mobile_1": "source/test.jpg",
"mobile_2": "source/test.jpg",
"mobile_3": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_1": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_2": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_3": "source/test.jpg",
"link_1": "#",
"link_2": "#",
"link_3": "#",
"tag_1": "Test 1",
"tag_2": "Test 2",
"tag_3": "Test 3",
"linkLabel_1": "Test 1 Go",
"linkLabel_2": "Test 2 Go",
"linkLabel_3": "Test 3 Go",
"title_1": "Test 1 Desc",
"title_2": "Test 2 Desc",
"title_3": "Test 3 Desc"
}
```

Is there an easy way to group these keys by a portion of the key name?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question, and perhaps better explain the problem you'd like help solving; as-written, I don't think I know what you want.

Comment: ohh sorry, i updated my question, i need the key to be grouped by index number in its current structure.

Comment: Do you mean something to the effect of `"_1" = { mobile: source/test.jpg, desktop: ..., tag: ..., linkLabel: ..., title: "Test 1 Desc" }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you were putting group each key, by it's _# suffix, into a "group object".

First, iterate over each member and find a way to pull the suffix you're looking for.  Regex is perfect for this application.

```
for(var key in src){
  var key.match(/_\d/);
  // ...
```

Next, get well versed in bracket notation.  It allows you to "dynamically" access an attribute by a string or string variable; as well as further child objects.

```
// assume suffix==="_1" and key==="mobile_1" <-- Still in the for-loop
group[suffix][key] = src[key];
/* ^- Same as group["_1"]["mobile_1"] = src["mobile_1"];
   ^- Same as group._1.mobile_1 = "source/test.jpg"
   ^- Same as group = { "_1": { "mobile_1": "source/test.jpg" }};
*/
```

**Working example:**

```js
var group = { };

src = {
"mobile_1": "source/test.jpg",
"mobile_2": "source/test.jpg",
"mobile_3": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_1": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_2": "source/test.jpg",
"desktop_3": "source/test.jpg",
"link_1": "#",
"link_2": "#",
"link_3": "#",
"tag_1": "Test 1",
"tag_2": "Test 2",
"tag_3": "Test 3",
"linkLabel_1": "Test 1 Go",
"linkLabel_2": "Test 2 Go",
"linkLabel_3": "Test 3 Go",
"title_1": "Test 1 Desc",
"title_2": "Test 2 Desc",
"title_3": "Test 3 Desc"
}

for(var key in src){
  var suffix = key.match(/_\d/);
  // The following will create the new "group" in the 
  // master group variable if it doesn't exist
  if(!group[suffix]){ group[suffix] = {}; }
  group[suffix][key] = src[key];
}

console.log(group);              //grouped objects printed to log
alert(JSON.stringify(group) );   //sent to alert box so snippet runs.
```

Comment: thanks! yeah something like this, i just have to make the objects dynamic but thanks, this is what i'm looking for!

Comment: @Randell You can use the same concept of bracket notation to check if that sub-group object exists and add it if not.  I added it to the snippet.

Comment: cool! i also made a dymanic one, but your update is much simpler and easy to understand, thanks for this, buddy! :)